# Load ES5 and ES6 npm modules with traceur

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm using traceur to enable ES6 development under node.js via `traceur.require.makeDefault`.  This works without issue.

I use Gemfury as a private npm repository, this also works. I'm creating my own npm packages using ES6.  The challenge I ran into was how to support loading both ES5 and ES6 modules.  The typical `traceur.require.makeDefault` example code block skips anything that has the `node_modules` directory in the path.

Here's how I solved this problem:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var traceur = require('traceur');

require('traceur-source-maps').install(traceur);

function find_parent_package(filename) {
    var current = path.dirname(filename);
    while (true ) {
        var package_json = current + '/package.json';
        if (fs.existsSync(package_json))
            return require(package_json);
        var last_slash = current.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (last_slash === -1) return null;
        current = current.substring(0, last_slash);
    }
}

traceur.require.makeDefault(function(filename) {
    if (filename.indexOf('package.json') > -1) return false;
    if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) return true;
    var p = find_parent_package(filename);
    return p && p.es6;
});
```

And an example of a `package.json` for an ES6 module that works with the above code (some information has been removed for privacy):

```js
{
  "name": "ps-core",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "es6": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "basic-auth": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.10.6",
    "express-hal": "0.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.10.1",
    "traverson": "^0.15.0"
  }
}
```

Given a particular npm module path, this code walks up the directory tree until it finds a `package.json` file, reads it, and inspects the `es6` key.  If true, then it allows traceur to handle the file.

My question is this:  Given the above implementation, is there a better way to do this?